# AutoSizing in VisualStudio for Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

Don't we have "AutoSizing" feature in VisualStudio for Xamarin.iOS?. I believe it's available in Xamarin Studio.

Answer (score 1):

In Property When you uncheck the AutoLayout. then sizing will be the default behavior of Xib files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing problem with Visual studio storyboard then open your storyboard in Xcode and do whatever you want, there you can do autosizing easily. I would prefer to use Xcode only for any UI creation instead of Visual Studio layout editor.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the .storyboard file => click on one viewcontroller => properties => Layout tab

[image]

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/part_7_-_layout_options_and_themes/